# how to put style css for image on gridview

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i am trying to set width and height on my phone in my gridview this is my code

```
[   'attribute' => 'iduser.photo',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value'=>  function($data) { return Html::img($data->imageurl,['id'=>'photo']); },
        ],
```

i have tried with this

```
 [   'attribute' => 'iduser.photo',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value'=>  function($data) { return Html::img($data->imageurl,['image'=>'100']); },
        ],
```

but i cant put px or percent for that

where i put class for css or set style ?

Comment: return Html::img($data->imageurl,['id'=>'photo', 'class' => 'some-classs', 'style' => 'border: 1px solid #000;']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got answer for my answer question.

this is the code

```
[   'attribute' => 'iduser.photo',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value'=>  function($data) { return Html::img($data->imageurl,['id'=>'photo']); },
            'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'max-width: 10px; max-height: 10px'],
        ],
```

thx google :p